# What's the derivative of $\frac{\cos((n+1)\theta)-\cos((n-1)\theta)}{2^n},\theta=\frac{x\pi}{n}$ for $x \in \{0,...,n-1\}$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> What's the derivative of $\dfrac{\cos((n+1)\theta)-\cos((n-1)\theta)}{2^n}$,
>   where $\theta=\dfrac{x\pi}{n}$ for $x \in \{0,...,n-1\}$ and $n$ is fixed?

So I've tried using the chain rule, and I got:

$a)$
$$\left( (n+1)\theta \right)'=\left( \pi x-\frac{x\pi}{n} \right)'=\pi(1-\frac{1}{n})$$

So because of that:

$$\left(\dfrac{\cos((n+1)\theta)-\cos((n-1)\theta)}{2^n}\right)'\stackrel{a)}{=}\dfrac{1}{2^n}\left( \pi(1-\frac{1}{n}) \sin(n-1)\theta- \pi(1-\frac{1}{n})\sin(n+1)\theta  \right)$$

But my textbook says, that it's

$$\frac{(n+1)\sin((n+1)\theta)}{\sin\theta } - \frac{(n-1)\sin((n-1)\theta)}{\sin\theta }$$

How come?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The book is obviously wrong. I think you are also wrong. The correct answer is $$ \dfrac {n \sin x \cos (nx) + \cos x \sin (nx)}{2^{n-1}}. $$

Comment: Then am I reading something incorrectly? Look here...: http://maths.whu.edu.cn/2012/szll/fjs/xxjskx/nxl/jxgz/201012/P020101202651492182888.pdf 
...in the middle of the second page.

Comment: Sorry, are you sure you sent me the correct link? The link you sent me has nothing to do with finding the derivative.

Comment: About equation (5) on the second page it says, that we get what I want by differentiating what I wrote above.

Comment: Huh. I don't see anything of the sort. I don't see anything which says "Equation (5)".

Comment: Damn, I sent the wrong link after all, here's the correct one: http://comjnl.oxfordjournals.org/content/15/2/156.full.pdf . 
So sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's the right link! No problem about the mistake, that happens. I've gone through your solution and the link and it seems like your solution is equivalent. Good work!

Comment: My solution is equivalent to the one I'm supposed to get by that document? How come?